# Remove weird space bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove some weird bottom space from the following markup:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
* Bootstrap
*/
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-left: .833333rem;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-right: .833333rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-left: -.833333rem;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-right: -.833333rem;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-left: .833333rem;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-right: .833333rem;
  position: relative;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-12 {
  right: 100%;
}
.col-xs-pull-11 {
  right: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-10 {
  right: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-9 {
  right: 75%;
}
.col-xs-pull-8 {
  right: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-7 {
  right: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-6 {
  right: 50%;
}
.col-xs-pull-5 {
  right: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-4 {
  right: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-3 {
  right: 25%;
}
.col-xs-pull-2 {
  right: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-1 {
  right: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-0 {
  right: auto;
}
.col-xs-push-12 {
  left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-push-11 {
  left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-10 {
  left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-9 {
  left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-push-8 {
  left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-7 {
  left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-6 {
  left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-push-5 {
  left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-4 {
  left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-3 {
  left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-push-2 {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-1 {
  left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-0 {
  left: auto;
}
.col-xs-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix::after,
.container::after,
.container-fluid::after,
.row::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no `padding`, so I don't know where the space comes from, see this `js`

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/czfa6fgq/2/

Comment: which whitespace that you're referring to?

Comment: i am using brackets on windows

Comment: Have you add CSS reset to your page?

Comment: jup the normalize.css which comes with bootstrap, but there are two solutions below now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actual `whitespace` usually caused by the spaces in your HTML reflected for `inline` elements such as images..

You can remove it by making the image `display:block`

```
img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/czfa6fgq/4/)

Comment: ok thank you :) ... would also a html minimization remove this whitespace?

Comment: Not always...the `display:block` is usually your best course.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think from HTML parsing that is Div with some text in it that also has a Img in it. HTML if you make sure you remove everything text, then it works, but I guess it is safer to just make it a block, at least as long as the whitespace will be smaller than the image

Answer (score -1):

just few modification in your html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 row">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have added row class beside with col-md-12 because in bootstrap there is default padding so we need to make changes like this.